# Laravel controller parameter's purpose?

Tags: php, laravel

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function showProfile($id)
    {
        return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
}
```

Why do we put parameters on laravel controllers when we can use "Input::get(id)"?
Can anyone give a sample on a situation where I need to use parameters on controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your condition when you are using Input::get('id'), the request to show the profile will be something like

> yourdomain.com/profile?id=2

But if you want to show the profile of a user based on something like this one,

> yourdomain.com/profile/2

or

> ```
> yourdomain.com/profile/john
> ```

you need a controller parameter.

In the seconds cases you can simply then, bind your parameter to the User model.

```
public function showProfile(User $user)
{
    return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user);
}
```

Comment: does Input:get('variable') also work on form submitted via POST?

Comment: @anaval you can get your form inputs via `request()->all()` or `request()->get('variable')`